# Right access modifier for a Template Methods in a Parent Class

Tags: java

Can I make a Template method in an Parent Class private

I want to use the template Pattern in overriding a method in a child class so when the method is called in the Parent Class, the overrided non in the Child Class is executed, But I am not sure which access modifier to use to declare the method in the Parent class, I want to make the Method `private` or `protected` if possible

Comment: Private method cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

You cannnot access the `private` members of parent class. And if You make it `protected` then you cannot access from the non-child classes outside the package.

So if you need to acces the method from anywhere use `public` modifier. If you only need to access within the package use `protected`